# Error is now showing in Azure Function(Azure Cloud)

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

Script is working fine when I run it on my local PC. I am using VS code with azure function. When I am running the code, getting the exact error. But I put the on azure function (azure cloud) and run the code, there is no trace of any error. I could not find any solution for my problem. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

```
/* Connect Remote Server and do rest work */
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
var conn = new Client();
var fs = require("fs"); // Use node filesystem

const HOST = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
const POST = '22';
const USERNAME = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
const PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxx';

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    conn.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('SSH - Connection Error: ' + err);
    });

    conn.on('end', function() {
        console.log('SSH - Connection Closed');
    });

   conn.on('ready', function() {
       console.log('Client :: ready');
       conn.sftp(function(err, sftp) {
           if (err) console.log(err);
       });
   });

   conn.connect({
       host: HOST,
       port: POST,
       username: USERNAME,
       password: PASSWORD
   });
}
```

Comment: Since you are using an async function your console.logs are likely running after your function has returned.
You are not awaiting on `conn.connect` which will cause those logs to run outside the function execution context, which I guess is why you don't see them when running in Azure. 
Looking at the code it looks like you'll do better using callbacks instead of promises as you'll be able to call `context.done` on `error`, `end` and `ready`

Comment: Using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-promise moudle, I have solved my problem. Now I am getting exact errors in Azure Cloud. Thanks @nelak for your valuable feedback

Comment: Happy to have helped you. Let me know if you consider my previous comment enough as an answer and I'll repost it as such.

Comment: Yes, I have taken your last comment of using await on `conn.connect` that helps me to think use different node package. That's the reason I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-promise package.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an async function your console.logs are likely running after your function has returned. You are not awaiting on `conn.connect` which will cause those logs to run outside the function execution context, which I guess is why you don't see them when running in Azure. Looking at the code it looks like you'll do better using callbacks instead of promises as you'll be able to call `context.done` on `error`, `end` and `ready`